# Default styles not being applied in jqGrid

Tags: html, jqgrid

I am trying out the samples for jqGrid from http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html. The grid comes up with the data, but the default style (font size, height of the different blocks/rows etc) is not applied. By default style, I mean the one I see in the examples used in the trirand site.

How do I fix this?

Thanks
Vivek Ragunathan

**The code I used:**

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>JQGrid</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/sunny/jquery-ui.css' />
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/themes/ui.jqgrid.css' />

    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost:82/testbed/resources/jquery-1.7.1.min.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/js/jquery-ui-custom.min.js'></script>        
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/js/jquery.jqGrid.js'></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var lastsel2;

        $(function () {
            $("#list1").jqGrid({
                caption: "Trying out jqGrid for Points",
                url: <url>,
                editurl: <edit url>,
                mtype : "get",
                datatype: "json",
                colNames: ['id', 'Name', 'Age', 'Address'],
                colModel: [
                    { name:'id',        index: 'id',        width: 35, align:"left", editable: true, sorttype: 'int', editrules: { edithidden: true }, hidden: true },
                    { name: 'name',     index: 'name',      width: 35, align:"left", editable: true, editoptions: { size: '20', maxlength: '255'} },
                    { name: 'age',      index: 'name',      width: 35, align:"left", editable: true, editoptions: { size: '20', maxlength: '255'} },
                    { name: 'address',  index: 'address',   width: 35, align:"left", editable: true, editoptions: { size: '20', maxlength: '255'} },
                ],
                rowNum: 10,
                autowidth: true,
                height: 150,
                rowList: [10, 20, 30, 50, 80, 100],
                pager: '#pager1',
                toolbar: [true,"top"],
                sortname: 'created',
                viewrecords: true,
                altRows: true
            });

            $("#list1").jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager1', { edit: true, add: true, del: false });
        });
        }
    </script>

</head>

<body>
    <table id="list1"></table>
    <div id="pager1"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that the reason of described problem can be missing `<!DOCTYPE html ...>` line before `<html>`. It's important to gives web browser clear information which version and which dialect of HTML/XHTML language you use on your page. You use `<link ... />` on your page. So you tried probably to write the code in XHTML language. In the case you can use something like

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
```

instead of `<html>`.

Moreover I would recommend you include the lines

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

at the beginning of `<head>` (like in example from [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3afirst_grid)). If you loads other JavaScript files from the internet then you can load jQuery also from `http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js` or `http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js` for example.

You don't wrote which version of jqGrid you use. You should use the most resent version (currently it's 4.5.2) and includes `jquery.jqGrid.min.js` or `jquery.jqGrid.src.js` instead of `jquery.jqGrid.js`.

I would recommend you to use `gridview: true` and `autoencode: true` options in all your grids. Usage of `height: "auto"` seems me good too. I think that the option `sortname: 'created'` was an copy&pased error. You should use the name of some existing column of the grid.